# Package to test whether a string is in a list

Tags: conditionals, strings

Is there a package that provides a command for testing whether a string is in a list?  I saw several answers that define their own commands to perform this or similar tasks, but I prefer a "self-evolving", and well-documented solution for this kind of tasks.  More precisely, the command should be something like this

```
\IfStringInList{string}{list}{DoThisIfTrue}{DoThisIfFalse}
```

For instance

```
\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}
```

EDIT:  I'm not against defining commands.  I expected thas this natural functionality was present in a ready-to-use package, that can be accessed in a very simple way.

Comment: Is "list" always going to be defined as a comma-separated collection of strings?

Comment: Probably.  I think it is somehow natural, while `{}{}{}...`, for instance, is not.

Comment: you don't need a package `\in@` and `\ifin@` are predefined in the latex format.

Comment: @David:  Thanks.  This is interesting.  Should I use `makeatletter`/`makeatother`?.  I would like a plain simple command.

Comment: @ASdeL you need something to access commands with `@` but see Heiko's answer which is the same as mine (which I have now deleted)  but just packaged for actual use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xtring` package provides such command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\IfStringInList[2]{\IfSubStr{,#2,}{,#1,}}
\begin{document}
\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{True}{False}

\IfStringInList{Joe}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{True}{False}

\IfStringInList{ul,Ri}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{True}{False}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced with this.  I do not like that `\IfSubStr{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{ul,Ri}{True}{False}` is `True`.

Comment: Good recovery. +1

Comment: This solution works correctly even when the first argument is empty (`{}`) or a macro (`{\somemacro}`). +1!

Answer (score 11):

Simple LaTeX with the kernel command `\in@`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfStringInList}[2]{%
  \in@{,#1,}{,#2,}%
  \ifin@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}
\end{document}
```

### Manual solution without defining a command and without `\makeatletter`

As requested by the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260907/package-to-test-whether-a-string-is-in-a-list/260921?noredirect=1#comment625359_260921). I do not see a sense, not to define a macro.

```
\csname in@\endcsname{,Paul,}{,George,John,Paul,Ringo,}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname ifin@\expandafter\endcsname\csname iftrue\endcsname
  Beat it%
\else
  Roll it%
\fi
```

}

The lengthy replacement for `\ifin@` is needed, when this construct is inside another `\if` branch.

Comment: Odd I didn't see this but system says you posted a minute ahead of me, I'll delete mine:-)

Comment: @Heiko:  Nice answer, but you are still defining your own command.  Off course, the command can be removed, but then `makeat...` must be used between `begin/end{document}`.

Comment: @ASdeL what's to say against defining a command? (If you insist you can put the code in a package of your own and – voila – you have a package which provides the command that you want…)

Comment: @clemens:  See my edit in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

expl3 has this ready for use: `\clist_if_in:nnTF {<clist>} {<item>} {<true>} {<false>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \IfStringInList {mmmm}
  { \clist_if_in:nnTF {#2} {#1} {#3} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}% Beat it

\IfStringInList{ul,Ri}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}% Roll it
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a macro called `\IfStringInList` and implements it via a call to the Lua function `string.find` to set up "true" and "false" branches. Observe that both the target string and the search string can be quite general; in particular, the target string need not be a comma-separated collection of strings.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luastring" macro
\newcommand\IfStringInList[4]{%
    \directlua{if string.find(\luastring{#2},\luastring{#1}) then
                  tex.print(\luastring{#3})
               else 
                  tex.print(\luastring{#4})
               end}%
    }
\begin{document}
\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}% "Beat it"

\IfStringInList{Mozart}{GeorgeJohnPaulRingo}{Strum It}{Hum it} % "Hum it"

\IfStringInList{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{ul,Ri}{True}{False}    % "False"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for an already defined command `\IfStringInList` (or any other name) in a common package.

Answer (score 1):

Another way...  EDITED to allow blank fields `(A,,B)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\IfStringInList[4]{\stringsearch#1:#2,\relax\relax%
  \if T\found#3\else#4\fi}
\def\stringsearch#1:#2,#3\relax{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{#2}}{\def\found{T}}{%
  \if\relax#3\relax\def\found{F}\else\stringsearch #1:#3\relax\fi}}
\begin{document}
\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}

\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}

\IfStringInList{Yanni}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for an already defined command `\IfStringInList` (or any other name) in a common package.