# How to convert macro output to string

Tags: macros, expansion

I would like to be able to check if a number is in a list of comma separated numbers. The code here works if the list is hardcoded into the command: [Membership check on comma separated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287084/membership-check-on-comma-separated-list)

But, I would like the list of comma separated numbers to be a variable. Once I implement this (with \newcommand used to define the variable) the command breaks down. Why?

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifmember[2]{%
\in@{,#1,}{,#2,}%
\ifin@
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifmember{3}{3,4}{True}{False}
\newcommand{\foo}{3,4}
\ifmember{3}{\foo}{True}{False}

\end{document}
```

The output:

```
True
False
```

How can I change the command to make this work? I've tried all kinds of \expandafter to no avail.

(PS: another trivial coding idea taking an hour to implement in Latex...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

True, `\foo` is not expanded and therefore doesn't seem like a CSV within `\ifmember`. We can expand both arguments to ensure you're working with a full list:

> True
>   True
>   False
>   True
>   True

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifmember[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{,#1,}{,#2,}}\x%
  \ifin@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifmember{3}{3,4}{True}{False}

\newcommand{\foo}{3,4}%
\ifmember{3}{\foo}{True}{False}

\ifmember{44}{\foo}{True}{False}

\ifmember{\foo}{\foo}{True}{False}

\newcommand{\baz}{4}%
\ifmember{\baz}{\foo}{True}{False}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to generalize this macro to make it print the number of times it occurs? Outputs could be: 0=if FALSE; 1,2,3...=number of times it occurs if TRUE. Thanks

Comment: @Krantz: See [LaTeX count number of occurrences of a character in a string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336294/5764)

Comment: I tried that but it did not do the job. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698878/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-the-content-of-a-macro-string-outp

Answer (score 8):

No need to reinvent the wheel. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifmember}{mmmm}
 {
  \clist_if_in:onTF { #2 } { #1 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_if_in:nnTF { o }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ifmember{3}{3,4}{True}{False} (expected: True)

\ifmember{3}{ 3 ,4}{True}{False} (expected: True)

\newcommand{\foo}{3,4}
\ifmember{3}{\foo}{True}{False} (expected: True)

\renewcommand{\foo}{3, 4}

\ifmember{4}{\foo}{True}{False} (expected: True)

\ifmember{foo}{\foo}{True}{False} (expected: False)

\end{document}
```

`\clist_if_in:<args>` has the comma separated list in the first argument, the item to look for in the second one.

To be honest, I'd better split the check into two variants: one for a “naked” argument, one for a control sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifmember}{smmmm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% explicit argument
    \clist_if_in:nnTF { #3 } { #2 } { #4 } { #5 }
   }
   {% implicit argument
    \clist_if_in:VnTF #3 { #2 } { #4 } { #5 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_if_in:nnTF { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ifmember*{3}{3,4}{True}{False} (expected: True)

\ifmember*{3}{ 3 ,4}{True}{False} (expected: True)

\newcommand{\foo}{3,4}
\ifmember{3}{\foo}{True}{False} (expected: True)

\renewcommand{\foo}{3, 4}

\ifmember{4}{\foo}{True}{False} (expected: True)

\ifmember{foo}{\foo}{True}{False} (expected: False)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, here's a solution for your code: reverse the arguments, so you can easily reach the second with `\expandafter`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifmember[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifmember@aux\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\ifmember@aux[2]{%
  \in@{,#2,}{,#1,}%
  \ifin@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifmember{3}{3,4}{True}{False}
\newcommand{\foo}{3,4}
\ifmember{3}{\foo}{True}{False}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned that you tried with `\expandafter`, I provide an example exhibiting how first-level-expansion of  `\foo` could be accomplished using `\expandafter`.

Nonetheless I definitely prefer [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353573/118714) and [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353594/118714) to what I am about to provide.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifmember[2]{%
  \in@{,#1,}{,#2,}%
  \ifin@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\ExpandSecondArgumentOnceFirst[2]{%
  \expandafter\PassFirstArgumentToSecondArgument\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\PassFirstArgumentToSecondArgument[2]{#2{#1}}%


\begin{document}

\ifmember{3}{3,4}{True}{False}

\newcommand\foo{3,4}

\ExpandSecondArgumentOnceFirst{\ifmember{3}}{\foo}{True}{False}

% or:

\expandafter\PassFirstArgumentToSecondArgument\expandafter{\foo}{\ifmember{3}}{True}{False}

\end{document}
```

The gist of the trick is having TeX flip around macro arguments in order to temporarily have the second argument available as first argument and thus knowing exactly about the amount of `\expandafter` needed for "reaching" it.

Of course this trick can only be applied successfully in those special cases where first-level-expansion of `\ifmember`'s second argument's first token yields fully expanded the entire list and not something like `\barA,\barB` which would be the case with:

```
\def\barA{3}
\def\barB{4}
\def\foo{\barA,\barB}
```

In the latter case first-level-expanding `\foo` yields: `\barA,\barB` and not `3,4` while Werner's `\edef`-approach does not just first-level-expansion but does expand completely until there are no more expandable tokens and thus even in the latter case (and the like situations) yields `3,4`.

That's why I prefer Werner's answer and why my answer should not be taken for something suitable for all-day-usage but should be taken for a moot point showing how the trick could be done using `\expandafter` in your special case of first-level-expanding `\foo` already yielding the fully expanded list.