# Test whether a string is in a list with variable

Tags: conditionals, expansion, strings

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260907/1442), I'd like the following

```
\newcommand{\word}{Paul}
\newcommand{\butnot}{Joe}
\IfStringInList{\word}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}
\IfStringInList{\butnot}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}
```

to return `Beat it` and `Roll it`.

This has in principle been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401191/) but only with the help of 2 packages. It should, however, be possible much simpler with [the solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260921/1442), only that I couldn't figure out how to expand the macro? (Not even with the help of [this reference](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/info/macros2e/macros2e.pdf) :/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? You need to make sure that `\word` and/or `\butnot` get expanded first. This can also be achieved with some `\expandafter`s but since I am never sure how many of those one needs I use a more mundane but IMHO also more accessible syntax. Of course there are many tools that help you doing the same (but at the very moment of writing this I am fighting a conflict between `\tikzexternalize` and `xparse` so I feel this solution might be useful for some who have similar clashes).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfStringInList}[2]{%
  \in@{,#1,}{,#2,}%
  \ifin@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\IfStringInListExpandedDo}[4]{%
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\IfStringInList{#1}{#2}{\noexpand\edef\noexpand\tst{1}}{\noexpand\edef\noexpand\tst{0}}}%
\tmp%
\ifnum\tst=1\relax%
#3%
\else%
#4%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\word}{Paul}
\newcommand{\butnot}{Joe}
\IfStringInListExpandedDo{\word}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{abc \textbf{Beat it}}{cde \textit{Roll it}}
\IfStringInListExpandedDo{\butnot}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{abc\textbf{Beat it}}{cde \textit{Roll it}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly. I had tried `\edef` without success. How does that work? What is `\tmp` needed for?

Comment: Hm, this fails if there are macros (e.g. `\textbf`) in `Beat it` :(

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig This tells LaTeX to first expand `\word` (or `\butnot`) and then `\IfStringInList`. And no, `\textbf` and so on do not work in this version (but I didn't know that was a requirement).

Comment: Thanks. Not it wasn't an explicit requirement. But is it possible to make this work?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Yes, sure. `\edef\tmp{\noexpand\IfStringInList{\word}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{\noexpand\textbf{Beat it}}{Roll it}
\noexpand\IfStringInList{\butnot}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{\noexpand\textbf{Beat it}}{Roll it}}%
\tmp` You need to make sure that these get expanded only in the very end, when `\IfStringInList` gets expanded.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig I rewrote my answer in such a way that you can use `\textbf`  and that the code gets shorter.

Comment: Thanks. It's still very fragile, e.g. having additional text before `\textbf` would now cause it to fail.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Better now?

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Essentially a one liner with `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfStringInList}{mmmm}
 {
  \clist_if_in:neTF {#2} {#1} {#3} {#4}
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \clist_if_in:nn {ne} {T,F,TF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\word}{Paul}
\newcommand{\butnot}{Joe}

\IfStringInList{\word}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}

\IfStringInList{\butnot}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{Beat it}{Roll it}

\end{document}
```

With `e` we force full expansion of the first argument.

[image]

By the way, `e` expansion is a big achievement in TeX Live 2019, available with all TeX engines. Since you're talking of *strings*, I suppose that the material in the search string is fully expandable to characters.

Comment: Oooh, `e`-type expansion!

Comment: @JosephWright I like to be modern. ;-)