# Conversion of a String to Integer

Tags: tikz-pgf, xstring, number

How can I convert a string of a small integer? In my code below, I check whether a string is a member of a list, which returns a string of "0" or "1". I am trying to use this returned value in `\fpeval` to make a decision using if-statement in the macro `\processNum`.

Could someone kindly please help me?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xfp}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\IfStringInList[2]{\IfSubStr{,#2,}{,#1,}} % Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260909/23594

\newcommand{\convertStringToInteger}[1]
{
     % I am trying to find a convertor
}

\newcommand{\singleBox}[4]{%
    \fill(\fpeval{#1}mm,\fpeval{#2}mm) rectangle
    (\fpeval{#1} mm + \fpeval{#3} mm,\fpeval{#2} mm - \fpeval{#4} mm);
}

\newcommand{\processNum}[5] %
{
    \fpeval{
       \convertStringToInteger{
          \IfStringInList{#1}{1,17,130,109}{1}{0}} ? #3 + 39 + (#4 + #5) + (#2-1) : 0 }
}

\begin{document}
    \IfStringInList{17}{1,17,130,109}{1}{0} % Works just fine. [for debugging purposes].
    \IfStringInList{16}{1,17,130,109}{1}{0} % Works just fine. [for debugging purposes].

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[draw=black] (0mm,0mm) rectangle (300 mm, 400 mm);
        \singleBox{100}{200}{24}{13} % This works just fine. [for debugging purposes]
        \singleBox{\processNum{1}{1}{0}{2}{1.46}}{200}{24}{13} % Fails at this line.
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tex doesn't have strings or integers, just lists of tokens so there isn't really a conversion between strings and integers, 123 is a string if you want to treat it as a string and an integer if you treat it as in integer

Comment: I thought the same thing, David. However, when I use it as a text with no conversion in `\fpeval`, the compiler complains about it. I posted a question that explains this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501749/23594

Comment: @AFP As already said, `\fpeval` cannot contain unexpandable material such as `\def`; `\IfSubStr` is included, because it performs several `\def`. And it's definitely not allowed in the `<test> ? <fp expr> : <fp expr>` syntax.

Comment: @egreg: Sure, seems impossible then. Would you please comment on checking the membership of an integer in an array of integers?

Comment: @AFP You should first try explaining what your aim is.

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501773/checking-if-an-integer-is-a-member-of-an-integer-list) where you already got an answer. Can we close here?

Comment: Note, it IS possible to pass `123` as an argument and parse it one token at a time, assuming you want to convert it to base 8 or something.  Or use modulo arithmetic on a \count register.